# It shows error after using geck V0.16.1

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

It shows error after using `geckodriver V0.16.1` Browser is getting opened and also URL is opened, but shows below error while opening browser:

> 1496729301597 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:26189
>
> 1496729302267 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser
>   \?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args
>   ["-marionette"]
>
> 1496729302562 addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [ExceptioJavaScript
>   error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1657:
>   NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
>
> n... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057
>   (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057
>   (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70" 
>   data: no] Stack trace:
>   FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 <
>   FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 <
>   validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:671 <
>   startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:834 <
>   startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3129 <
>   observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
>
> JavaScript error: resource://gre/components/SanityTest.js, line 65:
>   NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED: Component returned failure code:
>   0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIPrefService.savePrefFile]
>
> JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2570:
>   NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
>
> 1496729310139 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50194
>
> Jun 06, 2017 11:38:30 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession
>
> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

My code is as given below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 WebDriver driver ;
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.co.in");

}
```

Comment: It is nothing to do with your scripts. These are some javascript error from the webpage itself. You can also see these errors by manually launching the url and opening Dev tools and go to console

Answer (score 0):

May I know which selenium standalone server version you are using? It should work fine with 3.4.0

Comment: my selenium version is 3.4.0

Comment: what is your browser version?

Comment: Firefox version is 53.0.3